# issues with snap

Tags: snap

I'm trying to upload my unity game to the snap store using [this](https://ubuntu.com/blog/publish-your-unity-games-in-the-snap-store) tutorial but I have problem with Create a desktop file section
my desktop file code is [here](https://pastebin.com/MhEdCB1d)

Built it to snap and then installed it but when i try to open it won't start or say any errors

my snapcraft.yaml code [here](https://pastebin.com/b77mpwvS)

Comment: check from terminal - "snap run counterbullet"

Comment: /snap/counterbullet/x1/bin/desktop-launch: line 593: /snap/counterbullet/x1/CounterBullet.x86_64: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, it has issues while building. Check:

```
tree /snap/counterbullet/current/
```

See what missing beside `CounterBullet.x86_64`. Or it could be in another folder like `usr/local/bin`